# Unpredictable FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

Why does `FileWriter` write different number of bytes? `FileWriter` delegates its `write(int)` method to `StreamEncoder`, but its code is not available. I know there are different encodings, but `FileWriter` doesn't provide a way to set one. Why should one use `FileWriter`, if its behavior is so strange?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("out.txt")) {
        fos.write(127);                     //writes 1 byte (for i<128)
        fos.write(2047);                    //writes 2 bytes (for 127<i<2048)
        fos.write(Integer.MAX_VALUE);       //writes 3 bytes (for 2048<i)
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Experiments.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Notepad shows only one symbol in file (if you comment the third fos.write there will be two symbols in notepad).
So how can I make it work and read my file unambiguously?

Comment: Read the documentation.  You're seeing a multi-byte encoding.

Comment: @SLaks To be fair, he did try to dig around: he looked for the `StreamEncoder` source but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice little puzzle!

What's happening is that the `int` you're providing is being converted to a `char`, and then it's going through a `CharsetEncoder` to turn it into bytes. Since you're not specifying an encoding, I strongly suspect you're ending up with UTF-8. UTF-8 encodes characters variously as one, two or three bytes.

The conversion from `int` to `char` will leave you with a 16-bit unsigned value. You might think that this would be encoded as two bytes, but ASCII characters get encoded as they are in UTF-8, which is why anything up to 127 is being encoded as a single byte. This, of course, means that some will now need more than two bytes (by a simple counting argument). When you give it 2047, that manages to get encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes; but your last example of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` gets encoded as three.

Note that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is being converted first to a 16-bit unsigned `char`, so its value is actually 65535.

The source for `StreamEncoder` isn't officially available, it seems, but it's [there if you look for it](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/1ad7fbef48d0/src/share/classes/sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder.java).

What Notepad's doing, I've no idea, but I suspect it doesn't support UTF-8.

Although I've tried to explain here what's going on underneath, the bottom line is that you shouldn't be using `FileWriter` to write anything other than characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't know about variable-width encodings. I thought it was using different encodings for different numbers whithout providing a way to set one, that's what confused me.

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter` is for writing character data. If you want to write binary data use `DataOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a `FileWriter` object, it defaults to your platform default character encoding.
Javadoc for `FileWriter` says:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character
>   encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify
>   these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a
>   FileOutputStream.

So, to set the encoding, instead of using `FileWriter`, use its parent class – `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.txt"));
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileStream, "UTF-8");
```